# Find a single regex to get words of 3 or more characters between two specific words

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a Regex (used in Java) to get all the 3 characters or more words between the following words (Peach, Apple) in all the following sentences:

```
Peach are nice fruits. Apple are not.
```

At this moment, I'm using the following parts:

```
\w{3,}\b
```

to get all the 3+ more characters words. I'm using positive and negative look behind to get the words between `Peach` and `Apple` like this:

```
(?<=Peach).*(?=Apple).
```

I can't use two regex and I can't use substring or any others techniques. Only one single regex to extract the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\G` for this in lookbehind:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=(?:\\bPeach\\b|\\G)\\W).*?\\b((?!Apple\\b)\\w{3,})\\b");

String msg = "Peach a nice family of fruits. Apple are not.";
Matcher m = p.matcher( msg );

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println( m.group(1) );
}
```

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- `(?<=(?:\\bPeach\\b|\\G)\|W)` will assert either literal `"Peach "` or `\G` in lookbehind
- `(?!Apple\\b)` will make sure full word `Apple` is not ahead of the current position
- `\\b\\w{3,}\\b` will match a full word with 3 or more characters after 0 or more arbitrary characters.

**Output:**

```
nice
family
fruits
```

---

If there are **multiple Peach and Apple in the string** then you can use:

```
String msg = "Peach, a nice family of fruits. Apple are not. Another Peach foo bar is here Apple end.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
      "(?:(?<=\\bPeach\\b|\\G)\\W)(?:(?!\\bApple\\b).)*?\\b((?!Apple\\b)\\w{3,})\\b");

Matcher m = p.matcher(msg);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
nice
family
fruits
foo
bar
here
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4xB7/7)

---

This clumsy looking regex will probably take care of many edge cases but it should be used only if requirements are for nested/unbalanced `Peach/Apple` pair:

```
(?:(?<=\bPeach\b(?!(?:(?!\bApple\b).)*?\bPeach\b)|\G)\W)(?:(?!\bApple\b).)*?\b((?!Apple\b)\w{3,})\b
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4xB7/8)

Comment: Te expression fails [when "Peach" is not followed by a space](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4xB7/5)

Comment: It's not clear what OP wants in the case where there are multiple Peach and Apple in the string. In such cases, this regex will match everything satisfying the condition between the first Peach and the last Apple.

Comment: Yes @nhahtdh, if there are multiple of `Peach/Apple` phrases in same line then [`(?:(?<=\bPeach\b|\G)\W)(?:.(?!\bApple\b))*?\b(\w{3,})\b(?=.*?\bApple\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4xB7/6) should work.

Comment: @anubhava: It fails for this string `Peach, a nice family of fruits Apple. Apple are not.`

Comment: Thanks I just stepped way from my laptop, will look into this as soon as I get back online.

Comment: ok edited further but at this point I would like to pause this academic discussion without knowing the actual requirements. There can be few other edge cases of nested & unbalanced `Peach/Apple` pairs where this regex may require changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a single regex that does all the work, you can also do it in two steps:

1. Match the substrings between the markers.
2. For each substrings, extract works with more than 3 characters.

This approach would result in simpler regex, and less prone to bug in edge cases.

Using the string below as example:

> Peach, a nice family of fruits Apple are not. Another Peach foo bar is here Apple. Apple Peach inside Peach then Apple Peach no no Apple

I use the regex `(?<=\bPeach\b).*?(?=\bApple\b)` to pick out the substrings
`, a nice family of fruits` ,  `foo bar is here` ,  `inside Peach then` ,  `no no` , then extract the words with 3 or more characters from these substrings.

**The regex above is only an example. Depending on your requirement in edge cases, you can customize the regex to extract only the substrings which you want to extract words from.**

You can change the regex above to `(?<=\bPeach\b).*(?=\bApple\b)` to get everything between the first Peach and the last Apple.

The output for the example above is:

```
[nice, family, fruits, foo, bar, here, inside, Peach, then]
```

**Depending on your need, you can change the regex as suggested above, or just simply filter the output.**

Full example code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;


class SO32415895 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Peach, a nice family of fruits Apple are not. Another Peach foo bar is here Apple. Apple Peach inside Peach then Apple Peach no no Apple";

        List<String> inBetween = findAll("(?<=\\bPeach\\b).*?(?=\\bApple\\b)", input);

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern WORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w{3,}\\b");

        for (String s: inBetween) {
            words.addAll(findAll(WORD_PATTERN, s));
        }

        System.out.println(words);
    }

    public static List<String> findAll(String pattern, String input) throws PatternSyntaxException {
        return findAll(Pattern.compile(pattern), input);
    }

    public static List<String> findAll(Pattern pattern, String input) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
        List<String> out = new ArrayList<>();

        while (m.find()) {
            out.add(m.group());
        }

        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you chose this 2 steps approach, where 1 regex does it all? I don't get the point.

Comment: @Mariano: It's less buggy and more maintainable than the 1 regex approach. Not that I haven't tried writing a single regex - it's extremely prone to subtle bug and hard to customize.

Comment: Failure edge case: `String input = "Peach, a nice family of Peach fruits Apple. But Oranges are not.";` It gives `[nice, family, Peach, fruits]`

Comment: @anubhava: It's intended output. My example also contains this case.

Comment: Not sure if we can say it is intended output. Desired output can be just `fruits` since that falls in the innermost pair.

Comment: @anubhava: Sorry, I mean it's the output is intended for the regex I posted above. As you also mention in a comment on your answer, without a clear specs, any regex would come with assumptions. I'm just suggesting an approach which is more readable and less buggy than single regex approach